# What is the best way to solve this issue illustration problem?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, illustration

I am designing a Halloween poster and the "hill" my characters are standing on is black and one of my character's pants is also black. So it's black on black and hard to distinguish where the pants "end." What do you recommend I do to solve this issue in the best way so that it looks good? I really don't want to change the color of the pants or the hill either; I want to keep them both black.

[image]

[image]

This is the idea I came up with, but am not sure if it looks weird or not. Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose two potential options:

1. Do nothing. The illustration looks fine as it is. The fact that the shorts and the background are the same colour won't be confusing to most people's eyes.
2. Make the shorts shorter so that they start above the horizon. This would mean that the two black areas don't meet.

To be clear, my suggestion would be to leave it as it is